# Inferred curried function signatures in F#

Tags: f#, type-theory

In this [article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/how-types-work-with-functions/#functions-as-output), this function

```
let adderGenerator numberToAdd = (+) numberToAdd
```

has this type signature

```
int -> (int -> int)
```

However, when I create this function, the inferred type signature is

```
int -> int -> int
```

1. Are these type signatures different?
2. If not, how can I annotate my `adderGenerator` so that it has the first type signature?

Edit 1
This is the best I could come up with so far:

```
type Generator = int -> (int -> int)
let adderGenerator: Generator = (+)
```

I don't like how it makes `adderGenerator` adopt a point-free style.

Edit 2
This seems to work:

```
let adderGenerator numberToAdd : (int -> int) = (+) numberToAdd
```

Comment: If it's like Haskell, those are the same. The grouping parenthesis are unnecessary.

Comment: The top answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470256/how-to-read-f-type-signatures?rq=1 offers a helpful explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type signatures are the same, the parentheses just help indicate that the body of the function results in a function being returned.

These three forms with the full type annotated are equivalent:

```
let adderGenerator : int -> int -> int =
    (+)

let adderGenerator (numberToAdd : int) : int -> int =
    (+) numberToAdd

let adderGenerator : int -> int -> int =
    fun numberToAdd -> (+) numberToAdd
```

The first form is just an alias for `+` and simply reiterates its type.

The second form is a function declaration that annotates the type of the argument and return type separately.

The third form is a variable assigned an anonymous function.

Only making one argument explicit seems a bit odd to me, however. You can avoid partial application entirely by making both arguments explicit:

```
let adderGenerator (a : int) (b : int) : int =
    (+) a b

let adderGenerator : int -> int -> int =
    fun a b -> (+) a b
```